# Eigen sum() to float

Tags: c++, tensorflow, eigen

I have a Eigen TensorMap in my custom tensorflow operation of type

```
Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float, 1, 1, long int>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer>
```

Picking number from it works:

```
float a = Tbuf(0);
```

But If want to sum it to scalar float

```
float b = Tbuf.sum();
```

I am getting an error

```
word2vec_kernels.cc: In member function ‘virtual void tensorflow::NegTrainWord2vecOp::Compute(tensorflow::OpKernelContext*)’:
word2vec_kernels.cc:516:29: error: cannot convert ‘const Eigen::TensorReductionOp<Eigen::internal::SumReducer<float>, const Eigen::DimensionList<long int, 1ul>, const Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<float, 1, 1, long int>, 16, Eigen::MakePointer>, Eigen::MakePointer>’ to ‘float’ in initialization
          float b = Tbuf.sum();
```

Comment: What`s the question?

Comment: How to cast Tbuf.sum() to float.
But I already found the answer...
`float b = ((Eigen::Tensor<float, 0, 1, long int> )Tbuf.sum())(0);`
I needed to cast it to Tensor so it gets evaluated, and then pick scalar from it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I forgot the tensor needs to be evaluated at first.

```
float b = ((Eigen::Tensor<float, 0, 1, long int> )Tbuf.sum())(0);
```